# How to iterate through deeply nested objects inside of a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, nested

I know there are plenty of questions about iterating through JSON objects but I haven't found one that quite relates to my exact problem. This is the JSON that I'm trying to iterate through:

```
psinsights = {
 "kind": "pagespeedonline#result",
 "id": "/speed/pagespeed",
 "responseCode": 200,
 "title": "PageSpeed Home",
 "score": 90,
 "pageStats": {
  "numberResources": 22,
  "numberHosts": 7,
  "totalRequestBytes": "2761",
  "numberStaticResources": 16,
  "htmlResponseBytes": "91981",
  "cssResponseBytes": "37728",
  "imageResponseBytes": "13909",
  "javascriptResponseBytes": "247214",
  "otherResponseBytes": "8804",
  "numberJsResources": 6,
  "numberCssResources": 2
 },
 "formattedResults": {
  "locale": "en_US",
  "ruleResults": {
    "AvoidBadRequests": {
      "localizedRuleName": "Avoid bad requests",
      "ruleImpact": 0.0
    },
    "MinifyJavaScript": {
      "localizedRuleName": "Minify JavaScript",
      "ruleImpact": 0.1417,
      "urlBlocks": [
      {
        "header": {
       "format": "Minifying the following JavaScript resources could reduce their size by $1 ($2% reduction).",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "BYTES",
         "value": "1.3KiB"
        },
        {
         "type": "INT_LITERAL",
         "value": "0"
        }
       ]
        },
        "urls": [
        {
          "result": {
         "format": "Minifying $1 could save $2 ($3% reduction).",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://code.google.com/js/codesite_tail.pack.04102009.js"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "717B"
          },
          {
           "type": "INT_LITERAL",
           "value": "1"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Minifying $1 could save $2 ($3% reduction).",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://www.gmodules.com/ig/proxy?url\u003dhttp%3A%2F%2Fjqueryjs.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2Fjquery-1.2.6.min.js"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "258B"
          },
          {
           "type": "INT_LITERAL",
           "value": "0"
          }
         ]
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   "SpriteImages": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Combine images into CSS sprites",
    "ruleImpact": 0.0
   }
  }
 },
 "version": {
  "major": 1,
  "minor": 11
 }
};
```

Now, I'm trying to write a function that iterates through all of the ruleResults objects and returns an array of the localizedRuleName properties. According to the JSON, ruleResults has three member objects (AvoidBadRequests, MinifyJavaScript, and SpriteImages). Each of these has a localizedRuleName property I'm trying to access, but when I print out my array, it's blank. Here's how I've written my function:

```
function ruleList(results) {

    var ruleArray = [];

    for(var ruleName in results.formattedResults.ruleResults){

       ruleArray[counter] = results.formattedResults.ruleResults[ruleName].localizedRuleName;
    }

    return ruleArray;
}

console.log(ruleList(psinsights));
```

Can you guys help me get on the right track? I used basically this same method to iterate through the pageStats of the JSON and it worked perfectly. I'm not sure why I can't get it to work with these deeper nested objects and properties.

Comment: You don't give a value to `counter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is not your iteration, but your undefined variable "counter".
Instead of using a counter can use the "push" function:

```
function ruleList(results) {

    var ruleArray = [];

    for(var ruleName in results.formattedResults.ruleResults){

       ruleArray.push(results.formattedResults.ruleResults[ruleName].localizedRuleName);
    }

    return ruleArray;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fo9h56gh/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Whoops I meant to take that counter when I first posted my code! The counter actually didn't work for me. I just tried your solution but it still is just printing out a blank array for some reason. Just to see what ruleName was, I logged it and it changes correctly from AvoidBadRequests to MinifyJavaScript to SpriteImages. I just can't wrap my mind around why my code wouldn't be grabbing each localizedRuleName and adding it to the array :/

Comment: Ok, this is weird... when I run your code in jsfiddle, it works! But when I run mine in a browser window, it doesn't.

Comment: mh, in this case i can't help :( can you try to create a fiddle which reproduces your problem?

Comment: I'll give it a try! The weird thing is when I'm looking at the console, the array is displayed as "Array [ ]". If I click on the array, the window that pops up to the right displays:

    Array[0]
    push: "Combine images into CSS Sprites"
    length: 0

Comment: Wow! Your code wasn't working for me because I was mistakenly typed ruleArray.push = "string here" instead of ruleArray.push("string here"). Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

you're probably getting a javascript error since counter is not defined. you can try this:

```
function ruleList(results) {

  var ruleArray = [];
  var counter = 0;

  for(var ruleName in results.formattedResults.ruleResults){

    ruleArray[counter] = results.formattedResults.ruleResults[ruleName].localizedRuleName;

    counter++;
  }

  return ruleArray;
}
```